# Where is the definition of function nanf() on linux

Tags: windows, nan, math.h

I am trying to look for definition and declaration of the function  nanf() - return 'Not a Number function, which is related to the floating point functionality on Linux gcc compiler environment - (glibc).

I need to use similar/same definition for nanf() on windows to build my code using Visual Studio.

I checked following header files in the Linux src/include folders but did not see anything related to nanf declaration.

/usr/include/math.h 
/usr/include/bits/nan.h

Any pointers will be helpful.

thank you,

-AD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The declaration is just (C99 §7.12.11.3):

```
float nanf(const char *tagp);
```

or macros that expand to something equivalent.  A conformant implementation is highly platform-specific, however, because the standard does not define how to interpret `tagp`, except to say that the behavior is equivalent to a certain call to `strtof`, and "The nan functions return a quiet NaN, if available, with content indicated through tagp."

Instead of trying to shoehorn C99 features into the one compiler and library that stubbornly refuses to even *try* to implement them, why not just use a real C compiler?  There are plenty out there.